# Textured sculpt brushes result in a bulging mesh

Tags: sculpting, brushes

I have some textured sculpting brushes that recently have started to bulge the mesh in a cylindrical-like pattern whenever I use them. I don't know if Blender has changed how it looks at sculpt texture height data or if I messed up some settings. I have customized my startup file within the context of sculpting, but all I've done is auto-import these textured brushes. I don't know if it's relevant but I'm using anchored brush stroked. This is on version 3.6.1.

I have had to re-customize my startup file several times, so it isn't out of question that I accidentally clicked some checkbox the last time I set it up. Pictures below:

This is what it should look like:
[image: A mesh sculpted using a textured sculpting brush]

Versus what it looks like now:
[image: A sculpted mesh bulging out with texture on top]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a while struggling with this as well but I finally figured it out. In sculpt Mode, under your "Brush Settings", click the "texture" dropdown menu, and switch the Mapping to **"View Plane"** When you import the brushes into Blender 3.5 and above, the default texture mapping is "Area Plane". Hope this helps!

[image]